# How to get MicroBlaze running on Papilio Pro

Tags: fpga, spartan, microblaze

I am new to the FPGA world, and there seems to be gazzilions of boards and FPGA vendors. I just bought the [Papilio Pro](http://papilio.cc/index.php?n=Papilio.PapilioPro), which is based on the Spartan 6 LX9, and although I can already bitstream basic VHDL designs, I was looking to install the MicroBlaze soft core; but there doesn't seem to exist a top-level component for the LX9. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to be aware that Microblaze is not free; you need to pay Xilinx a license fee to use it. Once you have done that, you will have access to the necessary files and development tools.

Comment: I already have the files (maybe it's because I'm an academic, dunno, but I downloaded them for free from the official site).

Comment: If you have the EDK version of ISE, you don't pay royalties for MB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroBlaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EDK to create the design.  If you don't have a BSB Wizard file for the board, you have to build it up by hand. If I recall rightly, the flow goes:

- Add microblaze
- Add LMB
- Add BRAM controller
- Add BRAM
- Add UART
- Add clock generator
- Add reset controller
- Update UCF file for Tx, Rx, Reset and Clock

Build a bitstream and then you should be able to use the SDK Wizards to build and run a Hello World app.

Then add interrupt controller & timer at least.   Then you can run xilkernel (or another OS).

Followed by an external memory controller, more timers, other peripherals that take your fancy

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to set up. the board package for your non supported board. if you don't want DDR memory support, then it is pretty easy to do so. just chose generic board, add the address of your devices on the board and the SRAM, after that you are ready to use it.
(Sorry Adnroid auto correct made this sound pretty stupid).